# Ordenação Matplotlib usando index como denominador das barras

Tags: python, matplotlib

estou num impasse e não encontro uma solução. Eu desejo gerar um Bar Plot a partir de um dataframe que está reordenado em ordem decrescente. Eu gostaria que o nome das barras fosse o índice (0 a 5) Quando eu ploto o meu plot, ele não aparece na ordem decrescente. Como eu posso mudar a ordem das barras?

Operações que eu já tentei:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.style.use('seaborn')
des = ['0. item A', '1. item B', '2. item C', '3. item D','4. item E','5. item F']
total = [100,75,5,30,3,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'des': des,
                   'total':total}) 
df = df.sort_values(by=['total'], ascending=False)

df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# Solução 1
xs = df.index
ys = df['total']

plt.bar(xs, ys, color='#DDA63A')
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# Solução 2:
plt.bar('index', 'total', color='#DDA63A', data=df)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
#Solução 3
plt.bar(df.index, df.total, color='#DDA63A', data=df)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, substituindo só essa linha eu tenho o erro 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sorted'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converta o índice para uma lista de string, é uma forma de burlar a ordenação cativa do matplotlib.

```
`xs = df.index.map(str)
 ys = df['total']
 plt.bar(xs, ys, color='#DDA63A')`
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: perfeito! Era exatamente o que eu precisava! Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é não usar Matplotlib, e sim o plot do próprio DataFrame do Pandas. Você pode ordenar o DataFrame e plotar da seguinte forma:

```
df.sort_values('total', ascending=False)[['des','total']].plot.bar();
```

[image: Plot ordenado]

Pra mais respostas semelhantes, em inglês: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902958/pandas-dataframe-bar-plot-with-sort-values-by-other-column

Comment: Eu gostaria de usar uma solução com o Matplotlib

Answer (score 1):

Uma das forma que podes obteres o resultado desejado é:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
des = ['0. item A', '1. item B', '2. item C', '3. item D','4. item E','5. item F']
total = [100,75,5,30,3,5]

df = pd.DataFrame({'des': des,
                   'total':total})
df = df.sort_values(by=['total'], ascending=False)

xs = df.index
ys = df['total']

plt.bar(sorted(xs), ys, color='#DDA63A')
plt.show()
```

Observe que a única alteração feita foi na penúltima linha reordenando a variável **xs** com a função **sorted()**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa resposta funcionou com o exemplo que eu criei para postar aqui mas não funcionou com o meu gráfico original, ele gera o erro TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable